# 't Hooft Anomaly Equivalent Definitions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-anomalies

I've seen a ['t Hooft anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_matching_condition#%27t_Hooft_anomalies) defined in two ways. Roughly, a theory has a 't Hooft anomaly when

1. Once the theory is coupled to a background gauge field $A$ (so study eg the partition function $Z[A]$), the symmetry of the theory is violated precisely when $A\neq 0$. *So this definition manifestly tells us that we cannot gauge the symmetry*

Or

2. The global symmetry survives and the Ward identities hold. However, the correlation functions are symmetric only at separated points, but contact terms can be symmetry violating. See eg p42 of [1], or [2].

How are these equivalent, if indeed they are? (I feel like I am probably missing something very simple!)

---

[1] https://www.sissa.it/tpp/phdsection/OnlineResources/16/SISSA_AdS_CFT_course2018.pdf

[2] arxiv 1702.07035

Comment: Can you give a reference for your second definition of a 't Hooft anomaly? Ward-Takahashi identities generally only hold "up to contact terms", so I'm a bit unclear on where exactly the difference to a non-anomalous symmetry is supposed to like here.

Comment: never seen your 2.

Comment: Link to abstract pages?

Comment: OK, Alexarvanitakis, but I trust the authors of [2]!

Comment: @SvenForkbeard sure so do I --- I don't think it's too simple that 1. and 2. are equivalent!

Comment: I'm coming to the same conclusion. I guess what I'm after is some explicit discussion of how they are related then.

Comment: I think they're referring to the presence of Schwinger terms in the relevant current correlators ("current" as in "current algebra"). I'm familiar with the T-duality situation: As it happens obstructions to T-duality --- which is essentially the same as an obstruction to gauging the relevant isometry on the sigma model--- correspond to the presence of Schwinger terms in the current current correlator. Alexeev and Strobl mention this very directly on page 9 in the link: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0410183.

Comment: Tentative general picture: consider a hamiltonian formulation, and a collection of noether charges generating global symmetries. If the brackets close (as A&S say), then one can consider the new system where the vanishing of those charges has been imposed as a physical state condition; this exactly the same as "gauging". However, if in the quantum theory the charge algebra acquires Schwinger terms, then this procedure is inconsistent. Another stringy example is presumably the central charge in the Virasoro algebra seen as a t'Hooft anomaly for the gauging of the Virasoro constraints.